# Exact collision detection for high-detail deformable triangular meshes

Tags: collision-detection, 3d-meshes, soft-body-dynamics

What robust methods or approaches exist for *exact* collision detection involving high-detail, deformable geometry?

The kind of mesh I am describing is a surface that is specified as a triangulated polyhedron and looks very similar to this:

[image]

For the specific application I am working on, I need to find all the contact points for colliding meshes that undergo subsequent deformation. Possible deformations that may occur during a collisional event:

**1)** the mesh decomposes, or fragments into smaller (triangulated) meshes

**2)** the mesh retains integrity but the vertex values of it's surface change

**3)** both of the above deformations occur

There is no real-time constraint; accuracy rather than performance is the critical factor.

Comment: Did you consider to use an already existing engine?

Comment: There is PKDGRAV: http://hpcc.astro.washington.edu/faculty/trq/brandon/pkdgrav.html which is similar but the code is not publicly available. Other engines are either encumbered by license restrictions (commercial or GPL) or targeted at games making them unsuitable in a scientific application.

Comment: Also, an external library, often introduces a large amount of unnecessary code that I am NOT prepared to read, debug and massage given the very specific problem that I am trying to solve.